# Winflip for ubuntu?

Tags: kde, application-switcher

When I had both Vista and 7 I found one feature I was constantly using mostly because it looked cool while doing something was winflip, where all the windows were stacked in a full 3d card view when I pressed a key combo. Is there any way to get something like that on ubuntu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**KDE Window Behavior**

KDE Sysyem Settings > Window Behavior > Task Switcher

The KDE has 'built in' many ways to navigate through the windows - one of them is the 'Flip Switch'

[image]

[image]

'built in' means: released with the KDE SC. The switchers can be styled with the layouts written in QML: https://techbase.kde.org/Development/Tutorials/KWin/WindowSwitcher

The styles can be shared, downloaded, with the 'Get New Window Switcher Layout' button.

Comment: thank you soooo much, that's exactly what I was looking for